# php-fpm child x exited on signal 9 and making php-fpm.log huge

Tags: php

I am using:

macOS 11.3.1

PHP 7.3.28 (installed with brew)

Nginx 1.19.10 (installed with brew)

I notice that `/usr/local/var/log/php-fpm.log` is increasing very quickly and soon even reach 10G+. It is writing logs like:

```
[14-May-2021 11:48:56] NOTICE: [pool www] child 17478 started
[14-May-2021 11:48:56] WARNING: [pool www] child 17478 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 0.000189 seconds from start
[14-May-2021 11:48:56] NOTICE: [pool www] child 17479 started
[14-May-2021 11:48:56] WARNING: [pool www] child 17479 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 0.000285 seconds from start
[14-May-2021 11:48:56] NOTICE: [pool www] child 17480 started
[14-May-2021 11:48:56] WARNING: [pool www] child 17480 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 0.000277 seconds from start
[14-May-2021 11:48:56] NOTICE: [pool www] child 17481 started
[14-May-2021 11:48:56] WARNING: [pool www] child 17481 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 0.000238 seconds from start
```

I stop the php service and then it stops logging. I am wondering what causes this. and `0.000189 seconds` is very strange.

I googled but got nothing useful, only this: [opcache_reset will cause running FPM process stop with SIGKILL](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75107&thanks=6)

I don't know if this is related to what happened to me.

Comment: I had exactly same issue today with php-fpm installed via homebrew on macos 12.4
restarting the php service stopped logging. but still looking for permanent solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @sMyles No. The problem still occurs occasionally even I am using macOS 12.6 and php@7.4 now

Comment: My log file was 158GB :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP v 7 error, I think it was fixed in rev ?7.6? And also recent v8 releases.   The bug can cause PHP to consume all 100% of CPU and just spin.

At the same time, even after moving to the latest rev of phpv8.0-fpm, I still see the error you note above and have been playing with memory limit to 128 MB.

Previously, my memory was consumed and ran out due to the prior bug, but also saw rapid memory consumption after applying it, and 128 MB limit slows memory filling and doesn't seem to run out or impact performance.

Note that `#top -o +%MEM` will show you the PHP process memory and CPU consumption and, if you monitor it, has indicated and correlated w these messages.

I still have every 15 mins a `www` pool child killed, but CPU utilization and memory seem OK.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is there any reference to the bug you are mention?